# open shadowbox div with php

Tags: php, joomla, shadowbox

I have a problem with my php code in Joomla. 
Shows all the titles that are in the database, but when I click on a title opens the shadowbox with div and always shows with the same title, description and date. why?

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

<ul class="mostread">
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
<li>
<a rel="shadowbox" href="#open"><?php echo $row->title ?></a>
<div id="open" style="display:none;">
<div id="content" style="color:#FFF; padding:10px;">
Title:<?php echo $row->titulo ?><br>
Descripton:<?php echo $row->descripton ?><br>
 Published:<?php echo $row->date ?><br>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Id of element could not be same so try to assign different id in each loop..

Comment: The `href` has an id and when you click it, it will lookup for an element with the same id(in this example `open`, so it will look for the div with id `open`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
<ul class="mostread">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
        <li>
            <a rel="shadowbox" href="#open_<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $row->title ?></a>    
            <div id="open_<?php echo $i?>" style="display:none;">
                <div id="content_<?php echo $i?>" style="color:#FFF; padding:10px;">
                Title:<?php echo $row->titulo ?><br>
                Descripton:<?php echo $row->descripton ?><br>
                 Published:<?php echo $row->date ?><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```